# Dynamic knockout template only accepting single elements instead of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

We're trying to setup a knockout template to lazy load the contents of a 'folder' on the site. I'm experiencing an issue where lists that I'm passing to the applyBindingAccessorsToNode function are throwing an error,

```
ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode($("#subnode-" + id)[0], {
        template: function () {
            return {
                name: "template-file-system-tree"
            }
        }
    }, ko.observableArray(testFileSystem[id]));
```

but if I just send a single item it works

```
ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode($("#subnode-" + id)[0], {
        template: function () {
            return {
                name: "template-file-system-tree"
            }
        }
    }, testFileSystem[id][0]);
```

I haven't had any luck finding documentation for applyBindingAccessorsToNode to see if maybe it won't take in a list... but it seems kind of pointless to have a template system that can't accept a list of items.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsafa32u/16/)

EDIT: My boss told me he only intended for us to use knockout for 'flat' lists and to just do it in jquery.  I will check answers against the jsfiddle code and we can hopefully find a solution for anyone having this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [applyBindingAccessorsToNode source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/f424bd85a698e77013737ce8b31c0689916ebe08/src/binding/bindingAttributeSyntax.js#L410) last parameter name is `viewModelOrBindingContext`, meaning knockout expects you to pass viewModel object or instance of `ko.bindingContext`.

So you can pass for example object `{ fileSystemArray: testFileSystem[id] }` as last parameter.